# What automatic overdraw elimination capabilities does Android provide?

Tags: android, performance, graphics

Romain Guy mentions that automatic overdraw elimination was introduced in Android 4.4/5.0 (see http://www.curious-creature.com/2015/03/25/android-performance-case-study-follow-up/comment-page-1/#comment-52600) but I haven't been able to find documentation or talks referring to it. Does anyone know any details?

Comment: "remove drawing instructions whose result would be covered by another opaque draw instruction"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the code that does this and verified it with Romain Guy: http://www.curious-creature.com/2015/03/25/android-performance-case-study-follow-up/comment-page-1/#comment-52608

It’s mostly just good at removing full screen backgrounds. See the linked code to see exactly how it works.